# plotting image on map

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I want to place a small image on a basemap at a specific coordinates what are the modification I need to do

```
def base_map(temp):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(360, 180), edgecolor='w')
    m = Basemap(projection='cyl', resolution='l',
                llcrnrlat=-90, urcrnrlat=90,
                llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180, )
    draw_map(m)

    m.bluemarble()

    plt.show()
```

this is the final result i'm trying to do  https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHLF6.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The relevant code snippet you need is given below, hope it helps.

```
# ...
# other lines of code go above

filename = "some_image.png"
lonmin, lonmax, latmin, latmax = (100.6377, 100.6447, 13.729, 13.7325) # just example
image_extent = (lonmin, lonmax, latmin, latmax)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.imshow(plt.imread(filename), extent=image_extent)
plt.show()
```